# Axiom of infinity

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Using the axiom of infinity, we can construct the following sequence of sets (elements in $X$) $$\{\emptyset\}, \{\{\emptyset\}\} ,\{\{\{\emptyset\}\}\}, ...$$

How do i show that the terms of this sequence are **pairwise distinct**?

Comment: What do you mean with *sequence* of sets and how do you construct it from the Axiom of Infinity?

Comment: By letting X be a set such that the empty set is a element of X and X having the property: for any x in X, one has {x} in X

Comment: Such a set is not guaranteed for AoI *alone* (in the formulations I know, that is: There exists a set $X$ with $\emptyset\in X$ and $a\in X\to a\cup\{a\}\in X$)

Comment: That's how my professor defines the Aol in the notes. I checked online and found that the formal statement of Aol is as you described.

Comment: Distinctness follows from extensionality. Before you could speak about sequence, you need something like the natural numbers...

Comment: Right, to speak of "sequences", you need to have proved that $\omega$ (the nonnegative integers) exists, and you need to have proved that you can define functions on it by induction. One definition of $\omega$ is: the least set that contains $\emptyset$ and is closed under successor, where successor(a) is $a \cup \{a\}$, and "least" means in terms of set inclusion.

Answer (score 2):

Let $X$ be a set with $\emptyset\in X$ and $a\in X\to \{a\}\in X$.
Then we can let (using Separation and Powerset)
$$N=\bigcap\{\,U\in\mathcal P(X): \emptyset\in U\text{ and }\forall a\colon a\in U\to \{a\}\in U\,\}$$
the "smallest" set with those properties.
That is, any subset of $N$ that contains $\emptyset$ and is closed under the successor operation $S\colon x\mapsto \{x\}$ is all of $N$. In other words: We can perform induction in $N$, one of Peano's axioms (axiom scheme, actually)! We also verify that the other Peano axioms hold, e.g., $0$ is not the successor of any other set (indeed, the successor of $x$ is $\{x\}$ and contains the element $x$). Thus $N$ is a model of Peano's axioms.
This is about as close to "those guys are all distinct" as you can get.

Note that (without using also the axiom of Foundation and others) it is consistent that $X$ (in contrast to $N$) does contain "duplicates" in the sense that it might contain an element $x$ with $x=\{x\}$. Then again, is it a duplicate if all we have to distinguish it from other elements is its identity, hence the only thing it is not distinct from is itself?

Comment: The successor operation is conventionally $x\mapsto x \cup \{x\}$

Comment: @BrianO: Obviously .@lemonCylon's professor doesn't follow that convention and postulate the existence of $X$. Also, have you read that sentence about "without using the axiom of foundation"?

Comment: I did. I was belaboring the point as to why $x = \{x\}$ violates Regularity aka Foundation :) -- it's obviously ill-founded w.r.t. $\in$. I mentioned the conventional definition of successor as a hint that the $N$ defined in the answer is not $\mathbb N$ alias $\omega$.

Comment: @BrianO: Oh sorry. I thought that was a critic that the answer contains errors, instead that was an aside. My bad.

Comment: And I could have been clearer about that -- so I zapped the original comment.